# How to add a logo in center of QR code in android using [zxing]

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I have generated a QR code using zxing library in Android. Now i want to add app icon in center of QR code. I have seen many QR codes with some image in center of QR code. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this out.

https://skrymerdev.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/qr-code-generation-with-zxing/